# Do we need to wait locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization: before to call CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus?

Tags: ios, core-location

Do we need to wait `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization:` before to call `CLLocationManager .authorizationStatus`? I would like to call `CLLocationManager .authorizationStatus` immediatly after I just create the CLLocationManager